# Conway Game of Life - cells won't appear on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a Conway Game of Life app in a canvas on a webpage.  However after writing the code, I cannot get the cells to appear on my canvas element.  Can you tell what I am doing wrong?

My guess is that is has to do with the functions for the buttons - the functions I wrote are supposed to initialize the game, but it does not happen.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
        var CONWAY = (function() {
            var my = {};
                var Board = function() { //create a game board object
                this.cells = {};  //collection object to hold cell coordinates
                };

                var Cell = function(x, y, alive) { //create a cell object
                    this.x = x; //the x coordinate for the cell
                    this.y = y; //the y coordinate for the cell
                    this.alive = alive;  //state to show if the cell is alive or dead
                };


                Cell.prototype = { //add isAlive method to the cell object
                    isAlive: function() {
                        return this.alive; //return cell's state
                    }
                };

                Board.prototype = {
                    addCell: function(cell) {  //the method to add a cell to the board
                        this.cells[getCellRepresentation(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell;
                    },
                    getCellAt: function(x,y) {  //returns the value of the specified coordinates
                        return this.cells[getCellRepresentation(x,y)];
                    },
                    getAliveNeighbors: function(cell) { //check nearby cells for states according to the rules
                        var x = cell.x;
                        var y = cell.y;
                        var aliveCells = 0;

                        for(var i = -1; i < 2; i++) { //look for live cells in the vicinity
                            for(var j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                                if(i === 0 && i === j) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                var currentCell = this.getCellAt(x + i, y + j);
                                if(currentCell && currentCell.isAlive()) {
                                    aliveCells++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        return aliveCells; //return the number of live cells
                    },
                    calculateNextState: function(cell) {
                        var tempCell = new Cell(cell.x, cell.y, cell.alive);
                        var livingNeighbors = this.getAliveNeighbors(cell);

                        if(cell.alive) {
                            if(livingNeighbors === 2 || livingNeighbors === 3) {
                                tempCell.alive = true;
                            }
                            else {
                                tempCell.alive = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if(livingNeighbors === 3) {
                                tempCell.alive = true;
                            }
                        }
                        return tempCell;
                    },
                    step: function() {
                        var cells = this.cells;
                        var tempBoard = {};

                        for(var c in this.cells) {
                            var cell = this.cells[c];
                            var newCell = this.calculateNextState(cell);
                            tempBoard[c] = newCell;
                        }
                        this.cells = tempBoard;
                    }        
                };

                function getCellPrepresentation (x,y) {
                    return "x" + x + "y" + y;    
                }



        var CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_X = 99;
        var CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_Y = 23;
        var randomInit = function(board) {
            for (var y = 0; y <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_Y; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_X; x++) {
                    board.addCell(new Cell(x, y, (Math.random() > 0.8)));
                }
            }
        };
        var draw = function(board, canvas) {
            var output = ' ';
            for(var y = 0; y <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_X; y++) {
                for(var x = 0; x <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_Y; x++) {
                    var cell = board.getCellAt(x,y);
                    output += cell && cell.isAlive() ? 'o' : ' ';
                }
                output += '\n\
                ';
            }
            canvas.html(output);
        };

        var doConway = function(body) {
            var board = new Board(); //create new board

            randomInit(board); //initialize board with random dead and alive cells

            draw(board, body); //draw the board

            return setInterval(function() { //update every 130 ms
                board.step();
                draw(board, body);
            }, 130);
        };

        my.initConway = function(id, body) {
            clearInterval(id);
            return doConway(body);
        };

        my.resetConway = function(id, body) {
            body.empty();
            clearInterval(id);
        };
                var conwayRandIntervalId = null;
    var conwayBody = getElementbyId('conway');
    var resetGame = function() {
        this.resetConway(conwayRandIntervalId, conwayBody);
    };
    var startGame = function() {
        conwayRandIntervalId = this.initConway(conwayRandIntervalId, conwayBody);
    }
    return my;
    }());


    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        div.conway {
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: courier;
            float: left;
            width: 500px; 
            height: 288px;
            background-color: #000;
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <button id='startCW' onclick="startGame();">Random Conway's Game of      Life</button> | <button id='resetCW' onclick="resetGame();">Reset</button>
        <div class='conway' id='conway'></div> 
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What if you remove the whole GoL implementation and just get drawing working first? Otherwise - you are building a house on a not well prepared ground.

Comment: As a general rule, you should cut your problem down to the smallest possible test case. This will not only help you organise your thoughts but also get you more help faster. In this case, add logging or use a debugger to see which functions are being called. Once you've followed the execution flow, you can identify the block of code causing problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a little bit of time, so I took the liberty of fixing this application.

The initial problem is you were not exposing the function startGame properly, the button has no way to trigger it. I exposed it through your `CONWAY` object by setting it on my. Then you were missing the `document` part of `document.getElementById`. Next you were trying to call `getCellRepresentation`, but it should have been `getCellPrepresentation`.

The next issue was related to having your script execute before the dom has been loaded. There are a few ways around this, such as using jquerys document load function and placing your logic in there, but the easiest way was to just put your script tag as the LAST tag in your body. As the browser iterates through the html, its going to build the dom elements, and then execute your code, which allows your `document.getElementById` to return the proper element. Doing this before the dom loads will always return null.

I changed your `canvas.html(output)` to `canvas.innerHTML=output`, as this was a dependency on jquery that I did not have on my machine. Either way is acceptable.

Finally I cleaned up your output. In your version the output was falling all on one line because you were doing things such as using spaces and \n's. Since we were in an html block I changed the output to `&nbsp;`'s and `<br />`'s. Another solution would be to use a `<pre>` element instead of a div, but I haven't tested this.

I may have gone a little too far with the help, so sorry if you were just looking for the reason there was no output. Post a comment if you have any questions :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        div.conway {
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: courier;
            float: left;
            width: 500px;
            height: 288px;
            background-color: #000;
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id='startCW' onclick="CONWAY.startGame();">Random Conway's Game of      Life</button> | <button id='resetCW' onclick="    CONWAY.resetGame();">Reset</button>
        <div class='conway' id='conway'></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var CONWAY = (function () {
        var my = {};
        var Board = function () { //create a game board object
            this.cells = {};  //collection object to hold cell coordinates
        };

        var Cell = function (x, y, alive) { //create a cell object
            this.x = x; //the x coordinate for the cell
            this.y = y; //the y coordinate for the cell
            this.alive = alive;  //state to show if the cell is alive or dead
        };


        Cell.prototype = { //add isAlive method to the cell object
            isAlive: function () {
                return this.alive; //return cell's state
            }
        };

        Board.prototype = {
            addCell: function (cell) {  //the method to add a cell to the board
                this.cells[getCellPrepresentation(cell.x, cell.y)] = cell;
            },
            getCellAt: function (x, y) {  //returns the value of the specified coordinates
                return this.cells[getCellPrepresentation(x, y)];
            },
            getAliveNeighbors: function (cell) { //check nearby cells for states according to the rules
                var x = cell.x;
                var y = cell.y;
                var aliveCells = 0;

                for (var i = -1; i < 2; i++) { //look for live cells in the vicinity
                    for (var j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
                        if (i === 0 && i === j) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        var currentCell = this.getCellAt(x + i, y + j);
                        if (currentCell && currentCell.isAlive()) {
                            aliveCells++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return aliveCells; //return the number of live cells
            },
            calculateNextState: function (cell) {
                var tempCell = new Cell(cell.x, cell.y, cell.alive);
                var livingNeighbors = this.getAliveNeighbors(cell);

                if (cell.alive) {
                    if (livingNeighbors === 2 || livingNeighbors === 3) {
                        tempCell.alive = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        tempCell.alive = false;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (livingNeighbors === 3) {
                        tempCell.alive = true;
                    }
                }
                return tempCell;
            },
            step: function () {
                var cells = this.cells;
                var tempBoard = {};

                for (var c in this.cells) {
                    var cell = this.cells[c];
                    var newCell = this.calculateNextState(cell);
                    tempBoard[c] = newCell;
                }
                this.cells = tempBoard;
            }
        };

        function getCellPrepresentation(x, y) {
            return "x" + x + "y" + y;
        }



        var CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_X = 99;
        var CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_Y = 23;
        var randomInit = function (board) {
            for (var y = 0; y <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_Y; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_X; x++) {
                    board.addCell(new Cell(x, y, (Math.random() > 0.8)));
                }
            }
        };
        var draw = function (board, canvas) {
            var output = ' ';
            for (var y = 0; y <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_X; y++) {
                for (var x = 0; x <= CONWAY_GLOB_MAX_Y; x++) {
                    var cell = board.getCellAt(x, y);
                    output += cell && cell.isAlive() ? 'o' : '&nbsp;';
                }
                output += '<br/>';
            }
            canvas.innerHTML=(output);
        };

        var doConway = function (body) {
            var board = new Board(); //create new board

            randomInit(board); //initialize board with random dead and alive cells

            draw(board, body); //draw the board

            return setInterval(function () { //update every 130 ms
                board.step();
                draw(board, body);
            }, 130);
        };

        my.initConway = function (id, body) {
            clearInterval(id);
            return doConway(body);
        };

        my.resetConway = function (id, body) {
            body.empty();
            clearInterval(id);
        };
        var conwayRandIntervalId = null;
        var conwayBody = document.getElementById('conway');
        my.resetGame = function () {
            this.resetConway(conwayRandIntervalId, conwayBody);
        };
        my.startGame = function () {
            conwayRandIntervalId = this.initConway(conwayRandIntervalId, conwayBody);
        }
        return my;
    }());


    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the help and the explanation.  However, with the changes - I now get an Uncaught ReferenceError stating both startGame and resetGame are not defined when clicking both buttons - do you know why?

Comment: I looked thru the code 3 times and can't find the difference.  But mine will not work here (http://jsbin.com/notadocu/1/edit) either...

Comment: I got it figured out, but the reset button does not work.  Netbeans is giving me the following error:Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (15:24:47:544 | error, javascript)
    at my.resetConway (public_html/index.html:147:18)
    at my.resetGame (public_html/index.html:153:18)
    at onclick (public_html/index.html:20:256)